# AS3 - How can I get an array of constants of a class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

```
static public const CONST_1 :String = "CONST_1";
static public const CONST_A :String = "CONST_A";

public var constantsArr :Array;
```

Is it possible to get an array of the class constant values without adding them manually like this:

```
  constantsArr = [ CONST_1, CONST_A ];
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871576/how-can-i-list-all-the-const-properties-defined-in-a-class

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using describeType it should be possible :

```
public class Constants
{
    static public const CONST_1 :String = "CONST_1";
    static public const CONST_A :String = "CONST_A";
}

var xmlList:XMLList = describeType(Constants).child("constant");

var constantsArray:Array = [];
for each(var key:XML in xmlList)
{
   constantsArray.push(key.attribute("name"));
}
```