# How to get random constant from class?

Tags: actionscript-3

is it possible to take a random constant from a class in AS3?

```
class Constat
{
    public static const constA:String = "const1";
    public static const constB:String = "const2";
    ...

    /** this method must return a random constant */
    public static function getRandomConst():String
    {
         -------------------------------
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`describeType()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) to collect all of the constants defined on your class, then select a random one from there.

```
public class Constat
{

    public static const constA:String = "const1";
    public static const constB:String = "const2";

    private static var _constants:Vector.<String>;


    public static function getRandomConst():String
    {
        if(_constants === null)
        {
            _constants = new <String>[];

            var def:XML = describeType(Constat);

            for each(var i:XML in def.constant)
            {
                _constants.push(i.@name);
            }
        }


        // Select random.
        var con:String = _constants[ int(Math.random() * _constants.length) ];

        return Constat[con];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could always just stick all of the values in to an array and choose one at random.

Comment: could you write more details about it? or code example? because i did`t find any info about how to do it.

Comment: have you worked with array's before? It's pretty straight forward. Once you've added your values to the array, you can just generate a random index to pick a value out of the array.

Comment: sorry maybe i didn`t understand your answer (english is hard for me). I thought that there were the way to convert this class in to an array with constants and then get random value. (by the way i have just found how to do that [get array of constants of class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596475/as3-how-can-i-get-an-array-of-a-constants-of-a-class) (but i thisk this solution is slow))    To store the array with constant`s names in class is not good solution for me(if i undestand your offer now) (but works good :)) )

Answer (score 0):

Set to the const name followed by a number. and using a Dictionary approach method with a `Math.random()`.

try this

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class MyClass extends Sprite
    {
        public static const constA:String = "00";
        public static const constB:String = "11";
        public static const constC:String = "22";
        public static const constD:String = "33";
        public static const constE:String = "44";
        public static const constF:String = "55";
        public static const constG:String = "66";
        public static const constH:String = "77";
        public static const constI:String = "88";
        public static const constJ:String = "99";
                             .
                             .
                             .

        public function MyClass() 
        {   
            MyClass.test();
        }

        public static function mapped(i:int):String
        {
            //65 is A
            return String.fromCharCode(65+i);                   
        }

        public static function test():void
        {
            trace(MyClass["const"+mapped(int(Math.random()*10))]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  your solution is pretty simple and good, but names of my constans are different

Comment: I edited. check please. this code Elegant. My idea is ​​mapping the numbers and the alphabet.

Comment: thank you again, but you didn`t understand.. I wrote constA and constB, but i made it for example.. real names are labrador, rottweiler and e.t.c

Comment: mitim gave acceptable answer, and I wrote him in comments that I found another good solution - [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596475/as3-how-can-i-get-an-array-of-a-constants-of-a-class).  i think your code will be useful later in another situation